# Apache default home - /home/$USER/www

Tags: apache2

I know I can do this to set up a www directory from my home folder

```
gksu gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

replace `/var/www` with `/home/myusername/www`

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But is there a way to use `/home/$USER/www`?

I don't want to use `localhost/~myusername` because it will mess up my code.

Basically I want to be able to login into different accounts on my laptop - one for work one personal - but have localhost default to the current logged in account.

Thanks, Russ

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. Apache is a system-wide web server, and Ubuntu is a multi-user system. Multiple users can be "logged in" at the same time, and Apache doesn't know anything about them.

You can however, simply set up multiple sites running on different ports, that point to different `DocumentRoot` directories on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to set an Environment Variable in the `.bashrc` script for each user, and then have the `000-default` vhost access that environment variable. You'd have to restart /reload apache everytime you log in, but it might work. See [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569080/how-to-define-a-variable-in-apaches-httpd-conf-file) for a little more information.

A simpler solution may be to set up more virtual hosts (use `000-default` as a starting point) and edit your `/etc/hosts` file for local dns resolution.